# How to Bind to a List inside an Observable Collection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a class that has 2 public variables a string and a List of a Custom Class.

I have setup Binding and it works great for the string but I can't get it to bind to the List.

Code Behind

```
public class RegKey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CEKeys> Key = new List<CEKeys>();
}

public class CEKeys
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgRegKeys" Margin="0,0,0,40" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Black" Width="60" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Black" Width="140" Header="Value"  Binding="{Binding Path=Key.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Black" Width="140" Header="Type"  Binding="{Binding Path=Key.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How can I bind to the List of CEKeys while making the Value editable? Once the Value is confirmed I will be creating the keys that are listed.

While typing this I came upon a second issue. Each regkey has a List of Keys. This is because the RegKey may need to set multiple keys for it to work correctly. How can I also display all the keys in the List?

Comment: How youre adding values to this Name and list?

Answer (score 0):

The list is a field not a property and you can only bind to properties, you need to use:

```
public class RegKey
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<CEKeys> Key { get; set; }

   public RegKey()
   {
        Key = new List<CEKeys>();
   }
}
```

Comment: I did that but it still isn't working. The datagrid displays the Name attribute but not anything from the list.

Comment: @mac_attack18 run the program and look at the visual studio output window, you should find the binding error message there

Comment: BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' ''List`1' BindingExpression:Path=Key.Name; DataItem='RegKey; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : 

BindingExpression path error: 'Value' property not found on 'object' ''List`1'

I got this error for both Values What is it defining as List1?

Comment: Key object didn't have 'Name' property. The one that has 'Name' property is RegKey.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this to a list you could do this very easily:

```
public class RegKey
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<CEKeys> Key = new List<CEKeys>();
        Dictionary<string, List<CEKeys>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<CEKeys>>();
        public RegKey()
        {
            Key = new List<CEKeys>();

            dictionary.Add(Name, Key);
        }

    }
```